# why bind mount in docker not working in windows

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose

I am making a node app and I want docker compose to watch my updates and restart the server ,but the problem is that docker start the server but when I make update in my files it don't read it so I have to restart docker compose to read it

this is my dev script

```
"dev": "nodemon src/index.ts"
```

this is my image

```
FROM node

WORKDIR /app

COPY package.json .

RUN npm install

COPY . .

EXPOSE 5000

CMD [ "yarn","run","dev"]
```

this is my compose file

```
version: "3.9"
services: 
  backend:
    build: 
      context: ./ # file path
      dockerfile: Dockerfile # file name
    ports: 
      - '5000:5000'
    container_name: backend
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: ./
        target: /app
      # - ./:/app 
    env_file:
      - ./env/backend.env
```

Comment: It's probably due to this bug that makes it impossible to have containers watch file changes on Windows https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4739. As you can see, the bug has been open for nearly 2 years, so I wouldn't hold my breath for a fix.

Comment: I have found a work around , in windows 10 you can download ubuntu command line so you can work in it while you working in windows I have test it and it now working perfectly @HansKilian